# How can I dynamically sort a collection property in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

We have the following JPA class:

```
@Entity
class Supplier {
  // ... id property etc.

  @OneToMany
  @OrderBy("someProperty")
  private List<Region> regions;
}
```

This works fine in the normal case. However, we have some multi-lingual data where the values are stored in properties like `nameEn`, `nameDe`, `nameZh`. The exact property to use depends on the logged in user. For example, a German speaking user should see the regions as if it had been annotated with `@OrderBy("nameDe")`.

How can I achieve this?

I am aware I could sort the collection in my code after it has been loaded, but this makes pagination of the results quite difficult.

Comment: You can't embed that in the annotation since the annotations are processed once when the EntityManagerFactory is created for your persistence unit. What you're trying to do is similar to building a dynamic query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort them in java. Possibly in a getter:

```
List<Region> getRegions(){
  sorted = new List<Regions>(regions);
  Collections.sort(sorted, new RegionComparator(getUserLanguage()));
  return sorted;
}
```

Comment: What if you have 1000 items in the collection and you want to get only the first 10 sorted by some property. Doing this in dbms would be much more efficient

Comment: @LaurynasTretjakovas Then you'd simply iterate over the first 10 items after sorting. Not sure what makes you believe a database would be more efficient.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy because the database can use an index to sort the elements and if you have a lot of records you end up transferring way more data than you need over the wire.